# How do I charge a user to create a post using Stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

It's been surprisingly difficult to find more information on creating one-off, or single charges for a user. I'll probably write a straightforward guide following a working solution on my end.

Currently I am making a job board where anyone can browse listings, and a user (Devise) has CRUD abilities for a job posting. I want to embed a Checkout in the Job#new form and charge a user before the job is created. This Checkout would work with Stripe to capture credit card details, and not store the user as a repeating customer; a user should not have their credit card details stored on file and should have to input the credit card information each time they want to create a job.

Rough outline of how I'd approach this. Let me know if this seems logical:

1. adding the Stripe gem to the application’s Gemfile
2. create the actual charges in the existing Jobs Controller

#### JobsController

```
 |   before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]
 | 
 |   def new
 |     @job = current_user.jobs.build
 |   end
 | 

 |   def create
 |     @job = current_user.jobs.build(jobs_params)
 | 

 |     if @job.save
 |       # Pass Stripe::Charge.create
 |       redirect_to @job
 |     else
 |       # Handle rescue Stripe::CardError
 |       render 'new'
 |     end
 |   end
```

I'm not sure if this will have an impact on routes how this will change how I add the credit card form in Job#new in terms of getting the [:stripeToken].

```
  = simple_form_for(@job) do |f|
 |   = f.input :title
 |   = f.input :company
 |   = f.input :location
 |   = f.input :url
 |   = f.button :submit
```

Cheers

Comment: Have you looked at https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_charge, you can use stripe.js to generate the token and pass it to the charge endpoint.

Comment: The trick to any sort of checkout is that you can't charge and create the resource (such as an order) in the same request as you need to actually persist it first to get stuff like order numbers to link the payment to. Don't fall in the noob trap of trying to cram everything into a single action.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://launchschool.com/blog/stripe-checkout

Comment: Thanks for the insights everyone; that launchschool link is helpful...going to take a stab at it tonight and write up a quick guide if it works 